# Persist Correlation Id through HTTP requests

Tags: mule

In my mule flow the CorrelationId is set on the message, but after making an outbound `http:request`, the message loses the Correlation Id.

What is the correct way to prevent the Cid being lost?

**UPDATE**

No matter what I tried, the CorrelationId is always lost.  I've created a JIRA issue demonstrating the difference in behaviour between `http:outbound-endpoint` and `http:request`
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8522
I don't believe the CorrelationId is supposed to be lost in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the corrolation id in the message outbound so that it is available in external flow.

You can also look into the example to add Corrolation id in your message before sending to a outbound endpoint :- http://blogs.mulesoft.org/total-traceability/

**UPDATE**

Then use **message enricher** which wrapp the HTTP request component and by that way you can get the value from the external service without disturbing your actual payload and existing **corrolation id**
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Message+Enricher

Comment: External flows refers other flow, the flow inside you application or in any other mule application in the same server

Comment: My main flow is calling an external service to which I have no access.  But when that http:request completes, my flow continues (but now has no Correlation Id).    There is no external flow.

Comment: Try to set it in mule message outbound properties and check if it works

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that. 3 times now. haha. Still no luck.  Perhaps the other service needs to return it as a response header for it to go back into the message.

Comment: Check my updated answer and wrap the request component under a message enricher

Comment: The enricher works in the good case. But in any exceptional case (eg. the http request gets a 400), the flow jumps straight to exception handling from the enricher scope, thereby losing the correlationId.  The exceptional case is usually the case one would really want the ID.  Of course I could add error codes as "successful" and do my own code checking.. but I really expected this to be cleanly solvable

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end it was a bug in 3.6.0 that was fix in 3.6.1.  I appreciate your time and effort though.

Comment: After all, it's still not working. So I've used your enricher approach. Additionally I've saved the CID in a session variable for case when an exception occurs, so that I can reclaim it from the session variable to log the error. I created a JIRA issue demonstrating the change in behaviour since http:outbound: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8522